# How to schedule the Quartz cron jobs on spring boot app startup?

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, scheduling, quartz

I am integrating Quartz with Spring boot and postgres.
I have created all the required tables for quartz.

**Issue** : The application starts but the Job is not getting executed as per the cron.

I want that the jobs should be **automatically scheduled on start-up** and should run as per the cron expression.

But right now the application starts and no trigger is fired.

[image]

The QuartzJobFactory class

```
public class QuartzJobFactory extends SpringBeanJobFactory implements ApplicationContextAware {

    private transient AutowireCapableBeanFactory beanFactory;

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {

        beanFactory = applicationContext.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory();
    }

    @Override
    protected Object createJobInstance(TriggerFiredBundle bundle) throws Exception {

        final Object job = super.createJobInstance(bundle);
        beanFactory.autowireBean(job);
        return job;
    }

}
```

The ConfigQuartz class

```
@Configuration
public class ConfigQuartz {

    @Value("${quartz.dataSource.myDS.URL}")
    String orgQuartzDatasourceMydsUrl;

    @Value("${spring.datasource.username}")
    String orgQuartzDatasourceMydsUser;

    @Value("${spring.datasource.password}")
    String orgQuartzDatasourceMydsPassword;

    @Value("${quartz.enabled}")
    Boolean isQuartzEnabled;

    private static List<Trigger> triggers = new ArrayList<>();


    @Bean
    public JobFactory jobFactory(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        QuartzJobFactory sampleJobFactory = new QuartzJobFactory();
        sampleJobFactory.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        return sampleJobFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public SchedulerFactoryBean schedulerFactoryBean(DataSource dataSource, JobFactory jobFactory)
            throws IOException {
        SchedulerFactoryBean factory = new SchedulerFactoryBean();
        factory.setOverwriteExistingJobs(true);
        factory.setAutoStartup(isQuartzEnabled);
//         factory.setDataSource(dataSource);
        factory.setJobFactory(jobFactory);
        factory.setQuartzProperties(quartzProperties());
        factory.setTriggers(triggers.toArray(new Trigger[triggers.size()]));

        return factory;
    }

    public Properties setQuartzProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.URL",orgQuartzDatasourceMydsUrl);
        properties.setProperty("org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.user",orgQuartzDatasourceMydsUser);
        properties.setProperty("org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.password",orgQuartzDatasourceMydsPassword);
        return properties;
    }

    @Bean
    public Properties quartzProperties() throws IOException {
        PropertiesFactoryBean propertiesFactoryBean = new PropertiesFactoryBean();
        propertiesFactoryBean.setLocation(new ClassPathResource("quartz.properties"));
        propertiesFactoryBean.setProperties(setQuartzProperties());
        propertiesFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();
        return propertiesFactoryBean.getObject();
    }

    public static SimpleTriggerFactoryBean createTrigger(JobDetail jobDetail, long pollFrequencyMs,
                                                         String triggerName) {
        SimpleTriggerFactoryBean factoryBean = new SimpleTriggerFactoryBean();
        factoryBean.setJobDetail(jobDetail);
        factoryBean.setStartDelay(0L);
        factoryBean.setRepeatInterval(pollFrequencyMs);
        factoryBean.setRepeatCount(SimpleTrigger.REPEAT_INDEFINITELY);
        factoryBean.setName(triggerName);
        // in case of misfire, ignore all missed triggers and continue :
        factoryBean.setMisfireInstruction(
                SimpleTrigger.MISFIRE_INSTRUCTION_RESCHEDULE_NEXT_WITH_REMAINING_COUNT);
        return factoryBean;
    }

    // Use this method for creating cron triggers instead of simple triggers:
    public static CronTriggerFactoryBean createCronTrigger(JobDetail jobDetail, String cronExpression,
                                                           String triggerName) throws Exception {
        CronTriggerFactoryBean factoryBean = new CronTriggerFactoryBean();
        factoryBean.setJobDetail(jobDetail);
        factoryBean.setCronExpression(cronExpression);
        factoryBean.setMisfireInstruction(SimpleTrigger.MISFIRE_INSTRUCTION_FIRE_NOW);
        factoryBean.setName(triggerName);
        try {
            factoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            throw new Exception(e.getMessage());
        }
        triggers.add(factoryBean.getObject());
        return factoryBean;
    }

    public static JobDetailFactoryBean createJobDetail(Class jobClass) {
        JobDetailFactoryBean factoryBean = new JobDetailFactoryBean();
        factoryBean.setJobClass(jobClass);
        // job has to be durable to be stored in DB:
        factoryBean.setDurability(true);
        return factoryBean;
    }

}
```

The QuartzJobFactory class

```
public class QuartzJobFactory extends SpringBeanJobFactory implements ApplicationContextAware {

    private transient AutowireCapableBeanFactory beanFactory;

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {

        beanFactory = applicationContext.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory();
    }

    @Override
    protected Object createJobInstance(TriggerFiredBundle bundle) throws Exception {

        final Object job = super.createJobInstance(bundle);
        beanFactory.autowireBean(job);
        return job;
    }

}
```

The CronExpression class

```
public class CronExpression {
    private static final Map<String, String> cronExpressionMap = ImmutableMap
            .<String, String>builder()
            .put(TestJob.CLASS_NAME, "* 0 0 ? * * *")
            .build();

    public static String get(String key) {
        return cronExpressionMap.get(key);
    }
}
```

The TestJob class

```
@Component
@DisallowConcurrentExecution
public class TestJob implements Job {

    public static final String CLASS_NAME = "TestJob";

    private final String JOB_BEAN_NAME = CLASS_NAME + AppConstants.QUARTZ_JOB_SUFFIX;

    private final String TRIGGER_BEAN_NAME = CLASS_NAME + AppConstants.QUARTZ_TRIGGER_SUFFIX;

    @Override
    public void execute(JobExecutionContext jobExecutionContext) throws JobExecutionException {
        LocalDateTime start = LocalDateTime.now();
        System.out.println("*************** execute method is running *******");
    }

    @Bean(name = JOB_BEAN_NAME)
    public JobDetailFactoryBean sampleJob() {
        return ConfigQuartz.createJobDetail(this.getClass());
    }

    @Bean(name = TRIGGER_BEAN_NAME)
    public CronTriggerFactoryBean sampleJobTrigger(
            @Qualifier(JOB_BEAN_NAME) JobDetailFactoryBean jobDetail) throws Exception {
        return ConfigQuartz.createCronTrigger(jobDetail.getObject(), CronExpression.get(CLASS_NAME),
                CLASS_NAME);
    }
}
```

The main class

```
EnableConfigurationProperties
@EntityScan(basePackages = {"com.example"})
@ComponentScan({"com.example"})
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
public class QuartzSchedulerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(QuartzSchedulerApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/quartz
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=mysecretpassword
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.database=POSTGRESQL
spring.datasource.platform=postgres
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size=5

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults=false

quartz.dataSource.myDS.URL=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/quartz
quartz.enabled=true
```

The quartz.properties

```
#============================================================================
# Configure Main Scheduler Properties
#============================================================================
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName = PropScheduler
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId = 10
#org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId = AUTO
org.quartz.threadPool.class = org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount = 10
#============================================================================
# Configure JobStore
#============================================================================
org.quartz.jobStore.class = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX
org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass=org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.PostgreSQLDelegate
org.quartz.jobStore.useProperties = false
org.quartz.jobStore.dataSource=myDS

org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered = true

org.quartz.jobStore.clusterCheckinInterval = 5000
org.quartz.scheduler.name=test-schedulers

#============================================================================
# Configure Datasources
#============================================================================

org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.driver=org.postgresql.Driver

org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.maxConnections = 5
org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.validationQuery = select 1

#============================================================================
# Configure trigger history loging , enble if needed more information regaring triggers
#============================================================================
#org.quartz.plugin.triggerHistory.class=org.quartz.plugins.history.LoggingTriggerHistoryPlugin
#org.quartz.plugin.triggerHistory.triggerFiredMessage=Trigger [{1}.{0}] fired job [{6}.{5}] scheduled at: {2, date, dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS}, next scheduled at: {3, date, dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS}
#org.quartz.plugin.triggerHistory.triggerCompleteMessage=Trigger [{1}.{0}] completed firing job [{6}.{5}] with resulting trigger instruction code: {9}. Next scheduled at: {3, date, dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS}
#org.quartz.plugin.triggerHistory.triggerMisfiredMessage=Trigger [{1}.{0}] misfired job [{6}.{5}]. Should have fired at: {3, date, dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you see the CRON details being populated in CRON job table?

Comment: @BrianC No the CRON details are not getting populated in the CRON job table. I have attached the sceenshots of the each table data. I can see data in only two tables qrtz_scheduler_state and qrtz_locks.

Comment: TestJob isn't fired because you don't have a code that launches it as a Quartz job. Placing `@Component` on TestJob isn't enough

Comment: I see where you created the trigger, but do not see any place a scheduler was created and that trigger was attached to it.

Comment: @BrianC It is attached. If you see clearly in the ConfigQuartz class in SchedulerBeanFactory I am doing factory.setTriggers(triggers.toArray(new Trigger[triggers.size()])) where triggers is the list of all the triggers.

Comment: @smith were you able to solve this problem.

Comment: Were you able to solve the problem? I have the same problem, only the QRTZ_LOCKS and QRTZ_SCHEDULER_STATE tables are populated

Answer (score 1):

Your TriggerListener class (`SimpleTriggerFactoryBean`) doesn't seem to be implementing `TriggerListener` interface of quartz.

You can create custom class which implements `TriggerListener` and see if that works.

[Reference](https://github.com/sameer766/covid-vaccine-notifier/blob/master/scheduler/src/main/java/com/sameer/scheduler/service/SimpleTriggerListener.java)